# Writing a for loop for a numerical series in R

Tags: r

I'm not a R expert but I'm trying to understand the basics of the for-loop method. I'm trying to write a for-loop that prints the output as follows:

1
3
5
7
9
11

The code I am writing is below:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(i)
  print(i + 2)
  }
```

However, I'm getting the below output based on my code:

1 
3
2
4
3
5

It appears I am getting the first loop right but when it looks for `i == 2` and `i == 3` isn't not generating what I expect. What needs to be revised with my code so that my `i == 2` and `i == 3` is correct?

Comment: Do you really need to *print* it, or do you want to capture it so that you actually do something with it?

Comment: Probably this will help you: `seq(1, 11, 2)`

Comment: Think about it, though. The first time in the loop, `i` is 1, so you get `1` and `3`. The second pass in the loop, `i` is 2, so you get `2` and `4`.

Comment: @r2evans. I think he's just trying to learn about loops. Baby steps...

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to write a for-loop that prints the output as follows:
>
> 1 3 5 7 9 11

This is one way:

```
for (i in 1:6) {
  print(i * 2 - 1)
}
```

---

```
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 9
[1] 11
```

If you want to print it all on one line, then you'll have to save the results first, then print.

```
x <- NULL
for (i in 1:6) {
  x[i] <- (i * 2 - 1)
}
print(x)
```

---

```
[1]  1  3  5  7  9 11
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP has asked to revise his code to generate the expected result.

He has written a `for` loop with 3 iterations to print 6 figures.

So, the first iteration has to print the numbers 1 and 3, the second iteration has to print the numbers 5 and 7, the third 9 and 11. Each iteration advances the output by 4.

OP's approach can be modified to return the expected result:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(4 * (i-1) + 1)
  print(4 * (i-1) + 3)
}
```

or, less verbose

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(4 * i - 3)
  print(4 * i - 1)
}
```

> ```
> [1] 1
> [1] 3
> [1] 5
> [1] 7
> [1] 9
> [1] 11
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using the logic implemented by Edward, you can achieve the same output with `sapply`:

```
sapply(1:6, function(i) print(i * 2 - 1))
```